# Linux acting as USB device

Tags: linux, com, embedded, usb

I am working on an embedded Linux platform and I have need to transfer data between the platform and a PC. The embedded Linux has a USB device port (like a printer), so this is the means by which transfers would take place. I envision the easiest way to integrate Linux with the software already on the PC is to have the Linux device appear as a virtual COM port on the PC.

I'm not even sure where to start for this. Is there some standard Linux software for achieving this?

Answer (score 5):

You should check out http://www.linux-usb.org/gadget/, USB gadget API under Linux,

In the Linux source code tree, there is "Documentation/usb/gadget_serial.txt", 
this should explain how to make the device appear as COM port on connected host PC, provided that your hardware device USB port can work as USB slave, check your device documentation.